# Convert an XML to CSV with R when some nodes are missing

Tags: r, xml, csv, dataframe

I am using the xml2 package to convert an XML file to CSV. The XML I am dealing with has the following structure - note that `<businessAddress>` only appears in two of the `<business>` nodes.

```
<businesses>
    <business>
       <businessName>...</businessName>
       <businessAddress>...</businessAddress>
       <businessPostcode>...</businessPostcode>
    </business>
    <business>
       <businessName>...</businessName>
       <businessAddress>...</businessAddress>
       <businessPostcode>...</businessPostcode>
     </business>
    <business>
       <businessName>...</businessName>
       <businessPostcode>...</businessPostcode>
    </business>
</businesses>
```

My R looks like this:

```
data <- read_xml("/path/to/the/xml")

businessName_nodes <- xml_find_all(data, "//businessName")
businessName <- xml_text(businessName_nodes)

businessAddress_nodes <- xml_find_all(data, "//businessAddress")
businessAddress <- xml_text(businessAddress_nodes)

businessPostcode_nodes <- xml_find_all(data, "//businessPostcode")
businessPostcode <- xml_text(businessPostcode_nodes)

framedData = data.frame(
  businessName, 
  businessAddress, 
  businessPostcode,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

write.csv(framedData, file = csvName)
```

This gives me an `Error in data.frame... arguments imply differing number of rows` error because not every `<business>` contains a `<businessAddress>`.

My question is how to address this problem so I can end up with a frame where, when there isn't a `<businessAddress>` present, that there is a null value created

```
"", "businessName", "businessAddress", "businessPostcode"
9123, "Bob Smith", NA, "‎M1R 0E9"
```

Or failing that, that the row in the dataframe is not created at all.

New to R so appreciate help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `xml_find_first` from the xml2 package... Loop over the business-nodes, and if no xpath-match is found, the result is `NA`.

**sample data**

```
xmlText <- "<businesses>
  <business>
  <businessName>...</businessName>
  <businessAddress>...</businessAddress>
  <businessPostcode>...</businessPostcode>
  </business>
  <business>
  <businessName>...</businessName>
  <businessAddress>...</businessAddress>
  <businessPostcode>...</businessPostcode>
  </business>
  <business>
  <businessName>...</businessName>
  <businessPostcode>...</businessPostcode>
  </business>
  </businesses>"
```

**code**

```
library( xml2 )
library( magrittr ) #for the pipe symbol

doc <- read_xml( xmlText )

business_nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, ".//business" )

data.frame( 
  businessName = xml_find_first( business_nodes, ".//businessName" ) %>% xml_text(),
  businessAddress = xml_find_first( business_nodes, ".//businessAddress" ) %>% xml_text(),
  businessPostcode = xml_find_first( business_nodes, ".//businessPostcode" ) %>% xml_text(),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

#   businessName businessAddress businessPostcode
# 1          ...             ...              ...
# 2          ...             ...              ...
# 3          ...            <NA>              ...
```

Comment: Thanks this works. What is responsible for returning the "NA" in when there are missing nodes - that xml_find_first?

Comment: yes.. from the help-file: Use `xml_find_first` to find a specific match - if there's no match you'll get an `xml_missing` node.  If you then extract text from that node( `xml_text( xml_missing() )` ), you'll get `NA` as result